# PHP Undefined index:

Tags: php, html

I am new to PHP...
Just trying this simple piece of code inside my about.php file (which links to index.php file via a hyperlink):

```
<form action ="about.php" method="POST">
<ul>
    <li>
        <label for="name"> Enter your name please:</label>
        <input type="text" name="name"/>

    </li>   
    <li>
        <label for="comments" rows="20"> Enter your comments :</label>
        <textarea id="comments" name="comments" rows="5" cols="38">
            <?php 

                $name = $_POST["name"];

                if (!empty($name)) {
                echo "Your name is ".$name."and you like ny site!";
                } else {
                echo "Please enter your name";
                }


                ?> 
        </textarea> 
    </li>   
    <li>
        <input type="submit" />
    </li>   
</ul>
```

I get the following error:

**Notice**:  Undefined index: name in **D:\xampp\htdocs\stathis1\about\about.php** on line **71**
Please enter your name

Answer (score 1):

Because `$_POST["name"]` is not set, you get that notice. So you need to test if it exists first, and then assign it to your `$name` variable, or empty string if it's not set.

You can change

`$name = $_POST["name"];`

to

`$name = isset($_POST["name"])?$_POST["name"]:'';`

Comment: I dont get the error but still the program doesnt do what is supposed to, which is to to put the inserted name in the textarea...
I believe the cursor never enters the if (!isset($name)) condition...

Comment: don't forget to close the form with `</form>`

Comment: you can check the content of `$_POST` with `var_dump($_POST)`, and it might be a good idea to update your question with the changed code

Answer (score 1):

use isset() instead of empty() because isset() function not triggering notice when the index not defined.

Answer (score 1):

It's because `$_POST['name']` hasn't been submitted/set yet. You need to either use an if statement or a ternary operator:

```
if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];

    if (!empty($name)) {
        echo 'Your name is ' . $name . ' and you like ny site!';
    } else {
        echo 'Please enter your name';
    }
}
```

Or, a shorter method:

```
$name = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : '';
```

Answer (score 0):

Right after starting your php part add this if sentence surrounding the code, so it only executes when the "name" exists.

```
if(isset($_POST["name"]))
```

Like this:

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST["name"])){
        $name = $_POST["name"];

        if (!empty($name)) {
            echo "Your name is ".$name."and you like ny site!";
        } else {
            echo "Please enter your name";
        }
    } else {
        echo "Please enter your name";
    }
?>
```

Comment: I get "Please enter your name " in the textbox even when push the submit button after inserting a name in the name field....

Why name doesnt exist?